# UWP support for OpenCL

Tags: c#, c++, windows, uwp, opencl

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create a GPGPU program for UWP.

I tried compiling a simple OpenCL C program as a Windows Runtime Component and then using the component from a C# UWP application. Everything compiles, but the program fails when I try to instantiate an OpenCL context, resulting in an error with code 999 (unknown error).

The same code works in a basic console application.

For reference, the code is below.

```
int err;                            // error code returned from api calls

float data[DATA_SIZE];              // original data set given to device
float results[DATA_SIZE];           // results returned from device
unsigned int correct;               // number of correct results returned

size_t global;                      // global domain size for our calculation
size_t local;                       // local domain size for our calculation

cl_platform_id cpPlatform;
cl_device_id device_id;             // compute device id 
cl_context context;                 // compute context
cl_command_queue commands;          // compute command queue
cl_program program;                 // compute program
cl_kernel kernel;                   // compute kernel

cl_mem input;                       // device memory used for the input array
cl_mem output;                      // device memory used for the output array

                                    // Fill our data set with random float values

int i = 0;
unsigned int count = DATA_SIZE;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

// Bind to platform
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &cpPlatform, NULL);

// Connect to a compute device
int gpu = 1;
err = clGetDeviceIDs(cpPlatform, gpu ? CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Create a compute context 
context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
// ============= This is where err is filled with 999. =============
// ============= The context is null after the call. ===============
if (!context)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to create a compute context!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

What I find strange is that I am able to detect devices and instantiate a platform and a device correctly (it shows my GeForce 970 GTX correctly). However, it cannot instantiate a context and execute the rest of the code.

Is this a limitation of UWP? If yes, then is it reasonable to assume that the Desktop Bridge would be a futile endeavor as well?

Comment: Same for me. But with one note! It was impossible to create context for GeForce GPU but at the same time I was able to create context for IntelHD! Unfortunatelly, next instructions leads to other errors.